# keepass not working with wine

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, wine, keepass

I installed Keepass 1.16 in my thumbdrive, which reportedly works with wine (as per Keepass homepage), but after entering the master password it just hangs and shows the "The program keepass has encountered a serious problem and needs to close" screen.

I got this error msg among the stack trace on the terminal:

`wine: Call from 0x7b844633 to unimplemented function bcrypt.dll.BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider, aborting`

On windows, everything runs fine.

I'm using wine-1.1.27 on ubuntu 9.04

Any thoughts?

Comment: I preferred to use only one app on my thumbdrive for both plataforms, but I'll use KeepassX(linux) and keepass(windows) for the time being

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not familiar with Wine, but version 1.16 doesn't show up on t[his WineHQ listing for KeePass](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5780), so perhaps KeePass 1.16 isn't compatible.

However, there is cross-platform program [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/) that was forked from KeePass for Windows that you might want to check out. [How to install KeePassX on Ubuntu](http://www.keepassx.org/howto/setup/inst_ubuntu).

Comment: I use KeePassX (on Mac, though) and it is a good replacement.

Comment: 1.16 appears a compatible with wine on keepass HP.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to use the Keepass 1.x version, you should just use [KeepassX](http://www.keepassx.org/) instead.

It's as easy as adding the [KeepassX repository](https://launchpad.net/~keepassx/+archive/ppa) to your sources (via *System->Administration->Software Sources* : *Third Party Software->Add*), and then installing the package.

> sudo apt-get install keepassx

Note that if you're using Keepass 2.x versions on Windows that use the *.kdbx* file extensions, you're out of luck as even the latest KeepassX 0.4.0 Beta 1 version is not able to work with this. I stumbled across this issue and had to revert to using a Keepass 1.x version on Windows for compatibility.

**Edit:** As Decio pointed out in the comments, Keepass 2.x runs on the .NET framework, hence can be run under Mono, albeit using a Mono version that's not in the Ubuntu repository at this time.

There is even discussion on the KeepassX forums [about the future direction of the KeepassX project](http://www.keepassx.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1740), given that Keepass can now run in Linux and Mac under Mono.

Comment: Keepass 2.x supposedly work in linux if you have mono 2.2 or newer. Haven't tested that because ubuntu repos only have 2.0.x at this moment.

Comment: Wonderful! I didn't realize that Keepass 2.x was a ground-up rewrite on the .NET framework.